# Linear Search using python

Tags: python

Hi I am new to python and I am trying to learn it by writing linear search in python here is the code and this is the code I have written so far.

```
a = [100]

n = int(raw_input("Enter the no. of elements: "))

print "Enter the elements: "
for i in range(0,n):
    print i

item = int(raw_input("Enter the item to be searched: "))

for i in range(0,10):

    if a[i] == item:
        print "Item ", item, "found at location", i+1
        break;

if i == n:
    print "Item", item, "not found"
```

I get a error saying list index out of range, where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have a list with one element, i.e. `a[0] == 100`. Why do you expect it to have more?

Comment: Typically you loop from zero to `len(a)` to search a list. What is the 10 supposed to represent?

Comment: a = [100] # Defines a as a list with *one* element - 100

Comment: do `a = [0]*100` for storing list with 100 elements.. or else create empty list     `a = []` and add/ append values to it  in 1st `for loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slightly different (the sort algorithm)

```
a = []

n = int(input("enter number of elements: "))

print("appending elements: ")

for i in range(0, n):
    a.append(i)
    print(i)

item = int(input("enter the item to be searched: "))
# for python2.x please use raw_input

for i in range(len(a)):
    print("searching...")
    if a[i] == item:
        print("found! at: %s" % i)
        break
    else:
        print("pretty bad day, nothing found!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one element in your list. The second look tries to access elements 1 though 9, which are out of bounds.

I'd recommend using `enumerate`, which returns pairs of (index, element) up to the length of the iterable

```
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if x == item:
        # found item at position i
```

If you want to input number to generate a list of elements, then

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter the no. of elements: "))
# build your list of n elements here 
for i in range(0,n):
    print i
```

For example, `a = range(0, n)` or import the `random` module if you don't want a linear range of numbers

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code, I have tried to rearrange it:

```
a = []

n = int(raw_input("Enter the no. of elements: "))

print "Enter the elements: "
for i in range(0,n):
    a.append(i)
    print (i)

item = int(raw_input("Enter the item to be searched: "))

found = False
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i] == item:
        found = True
        print "Item ", item, "found at location", i+1
        break;

if (not found):
    print "Item", item, "not found"
```

Please note the following points:

1. Use lists and not arrays: `a = []`
2. Use the list operations: e.g. `a.append(i)` to insert an element to a list in the first free slot
3. Use the boolean values
4. Discover all the python functionalities ;)

Comment: Thanks. :) The above one worked I didn't consider adding the boolean values.

Comment: You are welcome! If the answer has been helpful for you, please press the up arrow ;)

Comment: Can press the up arrow until 10 rep, I believe. Also, why use `append`? `a = range(0, n)` works

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 . I suggested him to use the append  method because he is learning python and in the python language the list concept and the list operation are fundamental concepts.